# Calculate The Extent Of Non-Zero Values In An Array

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a 2-D numpy array `A`, how do I calculate the number of elements between the first non-zero x element and the last non-zero x element. So far I'm calculating the position of the index of the first non-zero element using

```
import numpy as np
A = np.array([[0, 0, 3],[0, 4, 2],[0, 7, 0],[0, 0, 0]])
for row in range(np.size(A,1)):
    if A[:,row].any():
        xMin = row
        break
print(xMin)
```

I could then do something similar for `xMax` starting from the end of the array and calculate the difference. The array represents a board and I want to find the range/extent of the items on the board. I wonder whether it might be possible using `np.nonzero()` to find the non-zero elements or stripping the array of non-zero elements. The simplest idea is to just loop over all the elements of the board and keep track of `xMin` and `xMax` but is there a more efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can do it using `np.nonzero()`. The first item is the first occurrence of non-zero items and the last one is the last occurrence. Then you can use the shape of your array (length of rows) to calculate number of items in between.

```
In [56]: x, y = A.shape

In [57]: (s, *rest, l),(ss, *rest, ll) = np.nonzero(A)

# without counting start and end
In [58]: (l - s) * y - (ss - ll) - 1
Out[58]: 4

# Counting start and end 
In [59]: (l - s) * y - (ss - ll) + 1
Out[59]: 6
```

Comment: Sorry I don't understand what you are doing there, the range of the row and columns with non-zero elements should be 2 and 3 respectively for this array. I don't understand what the numbers 4 and 6 represent. But looking at your code I think I've figured it out now, this works

    yCoords,xCoords = np.nonzero(A)
    deltaY = np.ptp(yCoords)+1
    deltaX = np.ptp(xCoords)+1

Comment: @s3nt1n3lz You mean you don't want to count the zeros?

Comment: Okay I understand what you are doing now, I should have been clearer. That's not what I meant. The non-zero elements take up a 3x2 block within the array of 4x3 which includes 2 zeros, so the answer is 3 and 2.